# Memory Leak C++ with class pointer

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

I trying to write some classes, learning c++ and have next problem:

**1. I have created class like**

```
class my_string
{
private:
    char* buf = nullptr;
    unsigned int size = 0;

public:
    my_string() : buf(nullptr), size(0) // default constructor
    {
    }

    my_string(const char* buffer) // constructor
    {
        size = strlen(buffer);
        buf = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (size + 1));//new char[size + 1]; // + 1 for the keeping the null character
        memcpy(buf, buffer, size);
        //strncpy_s(buf, size + 1, buffer, size); // copy from the incoming buffer to character buffer of the new object
    }

    my_string(const my_string& obj) // copy constructor
    {
        size = obj.size;
        buf = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (size + 1)); // + 1 for the keeping the null character
        memcpy(buf, obj.buf, size);
        //strncpy_s(buf, size + 1, obj.buf, size); // copy from the incoming buffer to character buffer of the new object
    }

    my_string& operator=(const my_string& obj) // copy assignment
    {
        // cleanup any existing data

        // Copy data from the newly assigned my_string object
        size = obj.size;
        buf = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (size + 1));; // + 1 for the keeping the null character
        memcpy(buf, obj.buf, size);

        //strncpy_s(buf, size + 1, obj.buf, size); // copy from the incoming buffer to character buffer of the new object
        return *this;
    }
};
```

2. I do something like:

```
    while (true) {
    
                my_string* www4 = (my_string*)malloc(sizeof(my_string));
                www4[0] = "kek";
                free(&www4[0]);
                free(www4);
    
            }
```

**And i have memory leak: process memory rise up to 150 MB for 1-2 seconds. What's wrong ? I free all ? no ?**

Comment: Please don't use `malloc` like this in C++. In practice you should use `std::string`. If the point is to implement a string class with custom memory management yourself, then at least use `new`. The comments even say it! In the case of `my_string* www4 = (my_string*)malloc(sizeof(my_string));` it is even undefined behavior. Furthermore, your `operator=` overwrites the buffer pointer without freeing it and you are lacking a destructor freeing the memory allocated by the class.

Comment: Added and no result: `~my_string() {

  free(buf);

 }`

Comment: user17732522, no, man, it isn't answer - i learn details of language and want know what's reason of this problem and what's my mistake and disunderstanding.

Comment: I gave you all the reasons in my first (edited) comment. You are using `malloc`/`free` where it should be `new`/`delete` (or direct value types) and there are deallocations missing in the destructor (which you fix in the comments) and the `operator=`.

Comment: i have fixed destructor method - but no result. What about malloc/free and new/delete - that's not "should" be. no difference.

Comment: Using malloc is not an undefined behaviour. It just have no reason to be used like that in C++. Malloc just allocates memory but doesnt call classe's constructor. Btw I totally agree with everything else that user17732522 says. Moreover you don't check on NULL in constructor - it is a bad thing.

Comment: Moreover you dont check on NULL in constructor - it is a bad thing. - how i should do it ? can you show it plz ?

Comment: If buffer is NULL don't do `strlen(NULL)` :))

Comment: @user11729819 `my_string` is not an implicit lifetime type. Therefore using the pointer returned from `malloc` as if there was a `my_string` object (in `www4[0] = "kek";`) causes undefined behavior. Though it is true that the call to `malloc` and the pointer cast themself are technically not UB.

Comment: " If buffer is NULL don't do strlen(NULL) :)) " lol, no, i dont understood you correctly, it doesn't matter in this sample code.

Comment: So, what does the C language tag have to do with the C language?  C and C++ are distinct languages.  For example, C++ has `new` which calls the constructor of a `class` or `struct`; `malloc` doesn't call constructors.  Please update your tags accordingly.

Comment: Do you not see that `free(&www4[0]);` and `free(www4);` attempt to free the same memory, you perform double memory free, that results in UB? Meanwhile the both `free` do not free `buf` memory.

Comment: "I do something like". What *exactly* do you do? Not what's something similar to what you're doing. You're certainly allowed to use malloc all you want in C++. It's not disallowed, but its use is extremely niche and you're unlikely to get help from people who want to help you do something in an old and error-prone manner.

Comment: The destructor is missing, as already mentioned. Also the size passed to `memcpy` is wrong, needs to be `+ 1` to include the null-terminator. Also `my_string* www4 = ...` is fishy, use `my_string www4;`. Then `free(&www4[0]); free(www4);` become unnecessary.

Comment: `free(&www4[0]`) is equivalent to `free(www4)`, so doing them both has undefined behaviour (since a pointer returned by `malloc()` should only be released once).   If you only do it once, `free(www4)` does not call destructors for elements of `www4`, so the memory allocated within your class constructors is never released.     Hence the leak.

Answer (score 1):

well if we go `c++` style then please add destructor to your `my_string` class :

```
~my_string()
{
    free(buf);
    buf = nullptr;
}
```

and replace those 2 `free` in your main by simple `delete www4` so it will look like this:

```
while (true) {
    my_string* www4 = (my_string*)malloc(sizeof(my_string));
    www4[0] = "kek";
    delete www4;
}
```

still not perfect `c++` code but at least you'll get rid of your memory leak.

ps: please use `new` and `delete` in your `c++` code.

Comment: And also replace the `malloc` used to initialize `www4` with `new`. Pretty important not to mix that up.